# WooCommerce hook for "after payment complete" actions

Tags: php, wordpress, paypal, woocommerce

I'm using WooCommerce and Wordpress. I have a custom license key generator, and I'd like it to generate a license key when someone successfully purchases my plugin through WooCommerce.

It seems pretty straight-forward:

1. User completes checkout on my site
2. User is re-directed to Paypal, where they enter their payment credentials
3. Paypal tells my site that the payment is complete
4. I hook in to some sort of "payment complete" or "order_complete" WooCommerce action and generate the license.

Here's the problem: I'm really not sure what hook would work well for this. Woocommerce has their [entire collection of hooks](http://docs.woothemes.com/document/hooks/) listed on their site, but virtually no documentation about which is good for what.

Based on just the hook names, I'd think that `woocommerce_payment_complete` would be a good action to use. Unfortunately it doesn't seem to be fired at all; some places I've read say that it isn't ever fired.

I've also read something about Paypal IPN, but I don't understand how I could hook in to the notification from that (does that connect to a Woocommerce hook?)

In short, I'd like to generate the license key as soon as the payment has been verified. What do I hook in to in order to achieve this?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Okay, I've come up with a couple possible solutions.

### DEALING WITH PAYMENT VERIFICATION

WooCommerce's Paypal Standard gateway actually has support for Paypal's IPN service built right in to it. You'll want to use that regardless of the 'hook' route you choose.

**HOW TO SET UP PAYPAL IPN**

Paypal IPN is connected to whichever account is the receiver of the money. For example, if you're getting paid at myemail@gmail.com, then you need to set up IPN with that account. All IPN is, is Paypal sending out a "Payment Complete!" (of sorts) notification to the URL of your choice. In order to choose the url that you want Paypal to send the notice to, you need to do these steps:

1. Log in to Paypal
2. Click on the little face icon on the top right
3. Click "Profile and settings"
4. Click "My selling tools" in the left sidebar
5. Find "Instant payment notifications" and click "Update"
6. Enable them and set the url. Your WooCommerce Paypal Payments Standard gateway url is: http://yoursite.com/?wc-api=WC_Gateway_Paypal (which is noted in WooCommerce's [Paypal Standard documentation](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/paypal-standard/#paypal-ipn-url)).
7. Save your settings

Your WooCommerce installation will now hear from Paypal when the payment is complete. Oh, and by the way, make sure that:

- Your "Receiver E-mail" in your Paypal settings is correct
- fsockopen is enabled on your server (you can check this "System Status" in your WooCommerce settings)

### NOW LET'S GET TO WORK ON THE HOOKS

**OPTION 1: Auto-complete orders that have completed payment and hook in to `woocommerce_order_status_completed` for your special actions/functions**

In order to get your products to auto-complete upon verified payment, you can simply install Mirko Grewing's fabulous [WooCommerce Autocomplete Order](https://wordpress.org/plugins/woocommerce-autocomplete-order/) plugin. Be sure to set the correct settings (which will appear under the "Woo Extra Options" tab in your WooCommerce settings).

Now that your orders are being autocompleted when the payments are verified, you can simply hook in to your completion hook, `woocommerce_order_status_completed, for your special functionality.

The benefit to that method is that if allows you to hook in any order that is completed--regardless of whether or not you manually completed it or it was automatically completed. In other words, it's pretty versatile.

**OPTION 2: Hook in to the `woocommerce_payment_complete_order_status` filter, which denotes a successful payment.**

I guess that one is pretty self-explanatory. The benefit to this method is that it's pretty much the first step in the whole process, and takes place prior to the completion hook above (if you have your priorities set appropriately).

I don't know if one is better than the other, but they both seem to accomplish my goal: perform an action AFTER payment has been verified.

Comment: Pete, Are you getting OrderID from this hook? I am not getting any data. Content posted is {"action":"woocommerce_payment_complete_order_status","arg":"processing"}

Comment: @PonSaravanan: The `woocommerce_payment_complete_order_status` filter takes two arguments. The first is the order status, the second is the order id. Alternatively, you can use the `woocommerce_payment_complete` action, which provides only the order id.

Comment: The dependence on Paypal means that any other payment method will not generate a license, which is very limited. Also, the dependence on yet another plugin causes an additional possible point of failure. Why not just use a basic woocommerce hook woocommerce_payment_complete? That way if you need to ever manually approve a payment (such as wire transfer or cash) your system will still work. See: http://stackoverflow.com/a/33821379/552983

Comment: Ummm...this doesn't depend on Paypal. :-) This only looks at when an order receives the 'complete' order status. Which means that it will also work with manually completed orders (there's even a line in my post that says "The benefit to that method is that if allows you to hook in any order that is completed--regardless of whether or not you manually completed it or it was automatically completed"). The extra autocomplete plugin simply removes the step of having to manually complete the orders when you receive payment.

Answer (score 20):

`woocommerce_payment_complete_order_status` also fires when the payment has been canceled. I've just tested using Paypal as a gateway on Woocommerce 3.1.2.

The action `woocommerce_payment_complete` seems to fire only when the payment has been successful.

Comment: Is this confirmed? Or does this fire on failed statuses?

Answer (score 4):

The `woocommerce_payment_complete` hook is activated only for orders that have one of the following statuses:

- on-hold
- pending
- failed
- canceled

#### HOOK: [woocommerce_valid_order_statuses_for_payment_complete](https://woocommerce.github.io/code-reference/files/woocommerce-includes-class-wc-order.html#source-view.111)

**If you change the order status** *(with a custom order status)* **before the payment is completed** (e.g. using the `woocommerce_new_order` hook, after the order has been created but before it has been paid for) you should add the new status via the [**`woocommerce_valid_order_statuses_for_payment_complete`**](https://woocommerce.github.io/code-reference/files/woocommerce-includes-class-wc-order.html#source-view.111) hook.

For example:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_valid_order_statuses_for_payment_complete', 'add_woocommerce_valid_order_statuses_for_payment_complete', 10, 2 );
function add_woocommerce_valid_order_statuses_for_payment_complete( $statuses, $order ) {
    $statuses[] = 'processing';
    return $statuses;
}
```

#### HOOK: [woocommerce_pre_payment_complete](https://woocommerce.github.io/code-reference/files/woocommerce-includes-class-wc-order.html#source-view.105)

Alternatively, you could use the [**`woocommerce_pre_payment_complete`**](https://woocommerce.github.io/code-reference/files/woocommerce-includes-class-wc-order.html#source-view.105) hook which is activated when the payment has been completed but before the order is saved *(unlike `woocommerce_payment_complete` which is activated after saving the order)*.

> The `woocommerce_pre_payment_complete` hook will always activate after
> a completed payment regardless of the order status.