# How to add PHP code custom functionality in woocommerce checkout transaction complete?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I wanted to add a functionality like calling an SQL procedure after a checkout transaction completed successfully. I tried searching for documentation but I can't seem to find it.

Comment: you need to add a hock : https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/woocommerce-order-status-control/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

seful action is **woocommerce_payment_complete**, called after the payment has been taken for an order. This is useful if you want to perform some automated task after payment has been taken:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_payment_complete', 'so_payment_complete' );
function so_payment_complete( $order_id ){
    $order = wc_get_order( $order_id );
    $user = $order->get_user();
    if( $user ){
       // do something with the user
   }
}
```

Find more on this. [URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33816480/woocommerce-payment-complete-hook)

Hope this will helps you.

Answer (score 0):

Hook in to the `woocommerce_payment_complete_order_status` filter, which denotes a successful payment.

```
<?php


add_action('woocommerce_payment_complete_order_status', 'function_to_run' );

function function_to_run($order_id) {
    $order = new WC_Order( $order_id );


   //Rest of your code

}
```